# Explicit BinaryFormatter serialization when Constructor is not called

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, binaryformatter, binary-serialization

**Some background about my problem:**
I have a lot of classes that implement `ISerializable` and are designed to be serialized using the explicit `BinaryFormatter` methods:
`.ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)` and `void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)`
I have recently discovered that `BinaryFormatter` does not always call the constructor when deserializing an object.
Supposedly, the `BinaryFormatter` is supposed to be copying the object graph bit-for-bit into memory, and so doesn't call the constructor on the 'Already Constructed' object.
This is not working for me: My private members are always null references when `OnDeserialized` is called and the constructor had not run.
This could potentially be resolved if I could still retrieve the serialized data collected by `GetObjectData`, but I cannot find anything but the constructor that gives me access to the `SerializationInfo` object.

**My question, then:**
Is there any way, other than `.ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)`, to retrieve the values that were collected during `void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)`?

**Or:**
Any clue how the `BinaryFormatter` decides whether to call the constructor or not? If I could just force the `BinaryFormatter` to always use the constructor, I believe my problem would be solved.

Comment: I have abandoned the `BinaryFormatter` in favor of `XmlSerializer`. It required a bit of effort to get our code entities switched over, but at least it's consistently calling `ReadXML()`.